# Are multiple updates to the same record allowed on REST Composite API?

Tags: rest-api

I don't see anything in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections_update.htm) for the `PATCH /vXX.X/composite/sobjects` REST API call prohibiting this, and indeed they imply that each object in the `records` array is processed independently, so it seems like it should work.

But a vendor who's using that endpoint to update Cases is getting `400 Bad Request` for request bodies that look like this, where there are several instances of the same record IDs:

```
{
    "allOrNone": false,
    "records": [
                {
                    "attributes": {"type": "Case"},
                    "id": "50042000006ZDovBAG",
                    "Comments": "Complaint has been accepted for investigation."
                },
                {
                    "attributes": {"type": "Case"},
                    "id": "50042000006ZDovBAG",
                    "Comments": "Additional investigation/inspection required. Property is Imminently Dangerous."
                },
                {
                    "attributes": {"type": "Case"},
                    "id": "50042000006ZDovBAG",
                    "Comments": "Complaint has been assigned to an a investigator."
                },
                {
                    "attributes": {"type": "Case"},
                    "id": "50042000006ZDovBAG",
                    "Comments": "Complaint has been accepted for investigation."
                },
                {
                    "Status": "Closed",
                    "attributes": {"type": "Case"},
                    "id": "50042000006ZDovBAG",
                    "Comments": "Case Concluded."
                }
    ]
}
```

Does anyone have a reference or definitive information that this is not allowed and would case the `400 Bad Request`?

(Yes, they should use `POST /composite/sobjects` with actual `CaseComment` records rather than using the `Case.Comments` shortcut when not also updating `Case` fields. But still hoping for definitive answer to this question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's allowed; I just tried this in my org and it worked successfully. Whatever is going on here is not related to providing the same ID multiple times.